# Convert digits in string to ints and then back to string

Tags: ruby

Say I have a string: `formula = "C3H12O4"`

How can I convert the digit chars in the string to ints?
My end goal is to do something along the lines of:

`formula * 4`

Once converted `formula` chars to an int, it would be best to report the result back to a string, thus

outputting as:

`"C12H48O16"`

Answer (score 2):

```
formula = "C3H12O4"
```

Code

```
p formula.gsub(/\d+/) { |x| x.to_i * 4 }
```

output

```
"C12H48O16"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had many conversions to do it might be worthwhile to include the following in a benchmark of different methods:

```
h = (0..9).each_with_object({}) { |n,h| h[n.to_s] = (4*n).to_s }
  #=> {"0"=>"0", "1"=>"4", "2"=>"8", "3"=>"12", "4"=>"16",
  #    "5"=>"20", "6"=>"24", "7"=>"28", "8"=>"32", "9"=>"36"}
```

Then for each string of interest the following calculation would be performed:

```
"C3H12O4".gsub(/\d/, h)
  #=> "C12H48O16"
"99Ra$32".gsub(/\d/, h)
  #=> "3636Ra$128"
```

This uses the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that employs a hash to make the substitutions.

A variant of this is the following.

```
"C3H12O4".gsub(/./) { |c| h.fetch(c, c) }
  #=> "C12H48O16"
```

Here `gsub` matches every character, which it passes to the block to be held by the block variable `c`. [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) is then used to look up and return `h[c]`, provided `h` has a key `c`. If `h` does not have a key `c`, `fetch`'s second argument (`c`) is returned.

The use of the hash avoids the need to convert back and forth between integers and strings, except in the creation of the hash, of course, but that is done only once.

Comment: As the numbers get larger, unfortunately, this method starts to fall apart. For instance, we're multiplying the original formula by 4 to get `"C12H48O16"`, if we then need to multiply that result by 4 again we get: `"C12H48O16".gsub(/./) { |c| h.fetch(c, c) } # => "C48H1632O424"
"C12H48O16".gsub(/\d/, h) # => "C48H1632O424"`

Comment: @SimpleLime, perhaps it's because I haven't had my morning coffee yet, but I don't understand your point. Perhaps you could contrast what I've done with Rajagopalan's solution.

Comment: `"C12H48O16".gsub(/\d+/) { |x| x.to_i * 4 } # => "C48H192O64"`...you're dealing with digits and end up essentially string concatenating `"H#{4 * 4}#{8 * 4}"` and getting `"H1632"` instead of dealing with numbers and multiplying`"H#{48 * 4}"` to get `"H192"`

Comment: @SimpleLime, this is yet another example of something we see every day at SO: a question being framed around a single example, rather than stating the question precisely and unambiguously, covering all possibilities, and using an example for illustration. Here the problem is made worse by an example that obtains the same result regardless of whether the question is interpreted as you and Rajagopalan did, that each block of digits is to be viewed as an integer, multipled by 4 and converted to a string, or as I did, that that is to be done for each digit.